# Spotify Auth Demo giving invalid client error

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, spotify

I am trying to get the Basic Auth demo from Spotify's SDK working. It successfully launches Spotify and redirects back to the app, but instead of authorizing the app it gives a code 0 invalid_client error. The demo app uses Spotify's Implicit Grant flow, so I shouldn't need to do anything to deal with refreshing authorization tokens.

I created a new application in the Spotify Developer portal and used the Client ID from a new application I made there instead of using the example Client ID in the demo app. I made sure the redirect URL, Client ID, and Bundle ID are consistent between the application and the developer portal.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm facing the same issue.